# how to format a POST request on apiary.io?

Tags: apiary.io, apiblueprint

thanks for your time
I have a POST request that I want to document in the blueprint apiary, the header is something like this:

text/html

_method:POST

data[User][username]:

data[User][password]:

data[User][remember]:0

http://d.pr/i/uRFx

I have something like this but I am not sure how to finish it:

```
## login [/users/login/{username}{password}{remember}{ident}]
Login with a user and password

+ Parameters

    + username (required, string, `myname`) ... the username format should follow CakePHP: data[User][username].
    + password (required, string, `whatever`) ... the password format should follow CakePHP: data[User][password]
    + remember (required, number, `0`) ... the remember format should follow CakePHP: data[User][remember]
    + ident (optional, number, `0`) ... the ident format should follow CakePHP: data[User][ident]

### make login [POST]

+ login by user (text/plain)
What goes in here???????????
```

any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Is this an URL-encoded form? Can you please click "view source" in your inspector (the screenshot you have attached). Also note there is the [cURL trace parser](https://github.com/apiaryio/curl-trace-parser) which can record a communication directly into API Blueprint

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean but this is the compleate screen shot of the request: http://d.pr/i/L256

Comment: BTW, this is the encode: http://d.pr/i/k6bS

Answer (score 12):

Apparently this is [submitting the data in a web form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms). In this case the `Content-Type` is of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type.

The message-body of the request has special formatting and also some of its charters (square brackets) have to be %-escaped. For the details on the formatting of the request body see [aforementioned Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms).

The API Blueprint in its simplest form could be something like:

```
# Login [/users/login]
## Make Login [POST]
+ Request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

        data%5BUser%5D%5Busername%5D=qq&data%5BUser%5D%5Bpassword%5Dqq&data%5BUser%5D%5Bremember%5D=0

+ Response 201
```

You should be able to see your example of request message-body in your traffic inspector under the "view URL encoded" link.

Refer to [this blueprint](http://docs.urlencoded.apiary.io) to see this example in action.

Also refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) for further details on `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: can you please post here the blueprint-markup of this??? -http://docs.urlencoded.apiary.io/ 
there are many missing samples of the blueprint and this one is really help full for me. Thanks!